# how can i pass from char[i] to a double?

Tags: c++, char, double, converters

I have information stored in an array of char and I would like to pass them to a single double value. 
As an example, I want to pass it from,

```
data[0]=3;
data[1]=.;
data[2]=1;
data[3]=4;
data[4]=1;
data[5]=5;
data[6]=1;
```

to

```
double data = 3.14151;
```

How can I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: What's the type of the first `data`? Also "`data[1]=.;`" is illegal.

Comment: The type of the first data is characters

Comment: You probably meant to use [`std::stod()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)!

Comment: If this is supposed to be a string containing Pi then the rounding seems off. 3.14159265, just fyi

Comment: No, the values are just to put an example. I guess that I ended up writing pi by luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use functions `std::stringstream` from `sstream` or [strtod](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) from `cstdlib` or [stod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/) (If you are using C++11) as per your need.

Quoting example from `cplusplus.com`

```
// stod example
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <string>     // std::string, std::stod

int main ()
{
  std::string orbits ("365.24 29.53");
  std::string::size_type sz;     // alias of size_t

  double earth = std::stod (orbits,&sz);
  double moon = std::stod (orbits.substr(sz));
  std::cout << "The moon completes " << (earth/moon) << " orbits per Earth year.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend these for [tag:c++]!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `sscanf()` for parsing even in C. Recovery in case of error is much harder to get right with `sscanf()` than with `strtol()` / `strtod()` and other, more dedicated functions. (`"%n"`? Not really...)

Answer (score 2):

I am *assuming* that your array actually contains *characters* and you just forgot the apostrophs. I used an easier, less error-prone way to initialize `data`, with the added benefit that my version actually does a zero-termination, which yours didn't (as Axel correctly pointed out).

```
char const * data = "3.1415";
```

The solution would be:

```
#include <cstdlib>

// ...
double number = std::strtod( data, NULL );
// ...
```

Check the `strtod()` [documentation](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtod/) for behaviour in case of error, and how to use the second parameter to check if your conversion actually went as far as you expected.

Comment: You should also do `data[7]='\0'` to avoid a segfault.

Comment: @Axel: Right, but you shouldn't initialize a char array like that in the first place. :-)

Comment: Now that gives you a +1 ;-)

Comment: That should be either `char data[] = "3.1415";`, or `char const* data = "3.1415";`.  Except that this is C++, so in practice, he'll want to use `std::string` (but `strtod` might still be relevant, particularly if he doesn't have C++11).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yep... that `const`... that's what my compiler *keeps* telling me as well, and I *keep* forgetting. ;-) That aside, he explicitly asked for `char[]`. And even for `std::string` I prefer running `strtod()` over string streaming, as the latter smacks a bit too heavyweight for my taste. (Actual profiling not done, just my gut.) And it's a shame how many commercial environments haven't embraced C++11 yet, so... `strtod()`, trusted and ubiquitous. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar I sort of agree with you with regards to `strtod`.  _If_ there's just the numeric value; beyond that, I'll instantiate an `std::istringstream` (or use `regex`, or...).  As for `stod` (and `boost::lexical_cast`), I think they just use `std::istringstream` under the hood, so any difference in weight is purely at the lexical level (which isn't to be neglected either).